# Listar o último registro de um campo da tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Estou querendo listar o último registro da tabela e exibir, mas não estou conseguindo.

A tabela reports tem o campo registration date duration  e destination_id

```
registration   date       time         duration         destination_id
    2501    2014-03-22  08:25:00  00:40:00(timestamp)      SBGL
    2501    2015-07-25  10:03:00  00:40:00(timestamp)      SBRJ
    5531    2015-09-15  19:24:00  00:40:00(timestamp)      SBSM
    5531    2015-10-19  10:15:00  00:40:00(timestamp)      SBBR
```

Quero mostrar o ultimo destination_id para o registration 2501 e 5531. Ou seja mostrar que:

```
2501 => SBRJ
5531 => SBBR
```

No cógido abaixo ele retorna:

```
2501 => SBGL
5531 => SBSM
```

Alguém ajuda pf?

```
$hours = mysql_query("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( duration ) ) ) AS duration_sum FROM reports GROUP BY registration");
$regist = mysql_query("SELECT registration AS regist FROM reports GROUP BY registration");
$model = mysql_query("SELECT equipment AS model FROM reports GROUP BY registration");
$base = mysql_query("SELECT destination_id FROM reports");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($hours) AND $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($regist) AND $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($model) AND $row4 = mysql_fetch_array($base)){

<tr>
  <td align="center"><div align="left"><? echo($row3['model']); ?></div></td>
  <td align="center"><div align="left"><? echo($row2['regist']); ?></div></td>
  <td align="center"><div align="center"><? echo($row['duration_sum']); ?></div></td>
   <td align="center"><div align="center"><? echo($row4['destination_id']); ?></div></td>
</tr>
  <?php
        }//while
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisas alterar a tua query para obter o `destination_id` correspondente à data mais recente. Isto pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
select registration, destination_id
from reports r
inner join 
( 
    select registration, max(timestamp(`date`, `time`)) maxT
    from reports
    group by registration
) MaxTime
  on MaxTime.registration = r.registration 
 and MaxTime.MaxT = timestamp(`date`, `time`)
order by 1
```

Para a seguinte estrutura

```
registration   date       time         duration                 destination_id
2501           2014-03-22  08:25:00    00:40:00(timestamp)      SBGL
2501           2015-07-25  10:03:00    00:40:00(timestamp)      SBRJ
5531           2015-09-15  19:24:00    00:40:00(timestamp)      SBSM
5531           2015-10-19  10:15:00    00:40:00(timestamp)      SBBR
```

A query irá produzir o seguinte resultado:

```
registration   destination_id
2501           SBRJ
5531           SBBR
```

Podes ver o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af2d4c/4)

Comment: O resultado está perfeito, mas como eu escrevo a linha:

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){

Comment: consegui obrigado!!!